# What are the defining characteristics of applied microeconomics papers?

Tags: applied-econometrics, research

I'm in bit of a fix. I'm trying to define my research interests and am confused whether or not to include applied microeconomics as one area. The way I see it is applied microeconomics is more of an umbrella term indicating methodology that can be used in various domains of economics.

I work with household/firm level micro data to explore issues in labor and education economics, although i have not used household/firm level optimization in my work. Should I just write intersection of labor and education, or applied micro is also applicable here? What exactly is the defining feature of an applied micro work?

Would appreciate your suggestions.
Thanks,
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universally agreed upon definition of "applied microeconomics", but if you follow the [description by Brown University's Department of Economics](https://economics.brown.edu/academics/undergraduate/areas-study/applied-microeconomics),

> The use of data and econometric methods to test microeconomic theory.
> Applied micro is an umbrella term that includes labor, urban,
> education, industrial organization, public, health, and environmental
> economics.

then you are definitely doing research in applied microeconomics.